# Google Analytics Core Reporting API - Cannot get information with batchGet without entering a metric

Tags: python-3.x, google-analytics-api, google-reporting-api

I'm trying to receive data from google analytics to make specific report.
This report does not include any metric but only dimensions.
The problem is that batchGet requests a metric in order to send a request properly.
This is the how the data is requested via Data Studio

[image]

As you can see the metric section is empty.
And this is how I run the batchGet request (using python)

```
analytics.reports().batchGet(
  body={
    'reportRequests': [
    {
      'viewId': VIEW_ID,
      'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '2022-01-01', 'endDate': '2022-01-01'}],
      'metrics': [],
      'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:date'},
                    {'name': 'ga:transactionId'},
                    {'name': 'ga:adContent'},
                    {'name': 'ga:source'},
                    {'name': 'ga:medium'},
                    {'name': 'ga:campaign'},
                    {'name': 'ga:keyword'}]
    }]
  }).execute()
```

When I run this code I get an error:

> "Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried together."

And that's because I ask both dimensions {'name': 'ga:transactionId'},{'name': 'ga:adContent'} in the same request.

How can I request this data and receiving this without any errors, because I know I can see it in Data Studio but I cannot request it via Google Analytics Core Reporting API.

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Not all dimensions and metrics can be queried together.

> Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried together.

Google Analytics has different scopes for dimensions and metrics: `Hits and Sessions.`  So when you build you report and you are calling  hits (or 'hit-level metrics'), you must call dimensions only within that scope.

There is no work around for this error  other than removing one of the offending items.  you can use the [Dimension and metric refrence](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/dimensions-metrics-explorer/) to see which one match.

Comment: So If I need both dimensions what can I do?
In Data studio I didn't need any metric to see this report

Comment: if you need both then you can pick which one you need the most because you cant have both.  The api will require you to have a metric.  API an data studio are not the same

Comment: You tried to make 2 request and after you can put the date together with the dates

Comment: @SebastianOffers thats not exactly how analytics works.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I finally found an solution.
I use 2 different requests with a unique field that will map between the transactionId field and the adContent field.

```
def get_campaign_report(VIEW_ID, analytics, specific_day):
  return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
          'viewId': VIEW_ID,
          'dateRanges': [{'startDate': specific_day, 'endDate': specific_day}],
          'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:transactions'}],
          'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:clientID'},
                        {'name': 'ga:visitLength'},
                        {'name': 'ga:date'},
                        {'name': 'ga:source'},
                        {'name': 'ga:medium'},
                        {'name': 'ga:campaign'},
                        {'name': 'ga:adContent'},
                        {'name': 'ga:keyword'}]
        }]
      }
  ).execute()

def get_transaction_id(VIEW_ID, analytics, specific_day):
  return analytics.reports().batchGet(
        body={
          'reportRequests': [
          {
            'viewId': VIEW_ID,
            'dateRanges': [{'startDate': specific_day, 'endDate': specific_day}],
            'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:transactions'}],
            'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:clientID'},
                          {'name': 'ga:visitLength'},
                          {'name': 'ga:transactionId'}]
          }]
        }
    ).execute()
```

Then I created dictionary for each request:
which the key is [{ga:clientID}{ga:visitLength}] which is pretty unique id and then I could mapping between {ga:transactionId} to {ga:adContent}